# ASP.NET Core Identity and Identity Server 4 - [Roles, Claims and IdentityResources]

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I would like to ask you for clarification when integrating IdentityServer 4 with ASP.NET Identity.

I am working with two database contexts.
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` and `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts.ConfigurationDbContext`.

Identity Server 4 is using AspNetIdentity `.AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()`.

So `IdentityUser` has assigned `IdentityUserClaims` and it's properly reflected in JWT token after successfull authentication.

Question now is, what is with the `IdentityResource` and `IdentityClaim:UserClaim` from IdentityServer4 `ConfigurationDbContext`? As claims are now used from aspnet identities, this entity is not used at all. Am I right?

Another question is how `ApiScopeClaims` are now in game? They are still used by the Identity Server because of `ApiScope` for which token is issued for. Right? But now it's up to me to keep in sync `ApiScopeClaim` and `IdentityUserClaim` which are from different db contexts.

Last Question is regarding `IdentityRoles` and `IdentityRoleClaims` which are not the same as `IdentityUserClaims`. What's the idea behind? In my idea, role is grouping of claims for specific business role for easier management, therefore role should not define new claims but reference set of `IdentityUserClaims`. Additionaly, I created role, assigned to user, corresponding claim types assigned to scope and result is that - claims which are assigned to role and user has this role are not included in JWT. Why?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

`IdentityResource` is a category or grouping of claims. Each `IdentityResource` can have many `IdentityClaims` which are references to actual the claims held in `AspNetUserClaims`. The built in `IdentityResources` are openid and profile.

ApiScopeClaims are part of the hierarchy of Api Resources (as opposed to the identity resources mentioned above.)

```
ApiResource --has many--> ApiScopes --has many--> ApiScopeClaims.
```

Adding a claim type to an `ApiScopeClaim` will attach an `AspNetUserClaim` (if one exists) to the `access_token` when when the User makes a request to that `ApiScope`.

An `IdentityRoleClaim` (i.e. `AspNetRoleClaim`) is just a bit a information you can tack on regarding a particular role; it does not related to a User, but just to the role itself.

Sound like you want to create an `IdentityResource` for your logical grouping of claims, and then define those claim types in `IdentityClaims`. But you would need a way to first find out the user's role in order to request the appropriate `IdentityResource` in `scope` parameter. Or implement one of the IdentityServer interfaces like `IProfileService` to do this kind of work on the IdentityServer instance.

Comment: And how is it please with the `IdentityRoleClaims`? They are part of of `AspNetIdentity` but are they included in JWT token issued by IdentityServer4? I tried that but they are not included, nor role claim is there.

Comment: When API Resource requires claim "role", role is included with proper value. But how include also role claims ?

Comment: Add the "role" claim type to the "openid" identity resource

Comment: Yes, this included role. But not role claims. Should I extend `.AddAspNetIdentity<>` ?